# Query for all primary keys in Db with a specific datatype

Tags: sql, database, oracle, plsql

I'm looking for all the primary keys in my DB that use the DATE datatype. Does anyone know a query to list the TABLE_NAME PK and it's datatype? Thank you

Comment: Have you tried joining `user_cons_columns` and `user_tab_columns`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This includes primary keys where only one of the members is a DATE.

```
SELECT cols.table_name, cols.column_name, cols.position, cons.status, cons.owner, atc.DATA_TYPE
FROM all_constraints cons, all_cons_columns cols, all_tab_cols atc
WHERE cons.constraint_type = 'P'
AND cons.constraint_name = cols.constraint_name
AND cons.owner = cols.owner
AND cols.TABLE_NAME = atc.TABLE_NAME
AND cols.COLUMN_NAME = atc.COLUMN_NAME
AND cons.owner = atc.owner
AND atc.DATA_TYPE = 'DATE'
ORDER BY cols.table_name, cols.position;
```